# Removal of side poll (community poll)

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

Im too new for magento! i wanna put off the currently magento community pool & recently viewed module -- but failed.

Its details like follow.
Location: Left side of the page.
Path: Categories section
Magento version: Magento ver. 1.9.2.1

Picture:
 [image: magento_poll_cannot_remove]

From the picture, there have recently viewed product module & also Community Poll. I need to remove all these modules/outputs.

> Blockquote

Some response to achieve that is go admin >> CMS >> poll

> Blockquote

But the issue is Poll option on Magento ver. 1.9.2.1 not available anymore.

Also, this have been done but no luck: Admin >> System >> Configuration >> Advance >> Advance: Mage_Poll Set to DISABLE.

What should i do now to make these 2 output disappear in any of the page?

Notice: Im on Magento ver. 1.9.2.1

Answer (score 5):

[The devs over at webguys.de recommending this:](http://www.webguys.de/magento/layout-updates-uber-die-local-xml/)

Create a local.xml file inside of your theme (if not already existing) and add:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
            <!-- Mage_Poll -->
            <remove name="right.poll" />

            <!--  Paypal ad -->
            <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo" />          
    </default>
</layout>
```

Beside this, they have a few more blocks for deletion, like callout, compared, recommended, etc.

Comment: it help on the blocked name :)
but it seem dont work if put in reference. I dont know why.

Comment: Thanks, reference is wrong, `<remove/>` should work everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I used to go with this but it doest work. What is work just like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <layout>
        <default>
            <remove name="right.poll"/>
            <remove name="left.reports.product.viewed"/>
        </default>
     </layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It IS available on 1.9.3.1
In Admin, go to CMS / Polls.
You can delete the poll or close it. A closed poll is not visible anymore on the sidebar.

Make sure the poll is disabled for all languages (store fronts) if you have multiple.